# Heroku: Rails 5 WebSocket connection failed

Tags: heroku, reactjs, websocket, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

i'm trying to deploy reactjs on rails 5 app on heroku this is my Procfile

```
web: bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

this is my puma.rb file

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 5000
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

and this is my cable.yml file

```
production:
:url: redis://redistogo:f9e8821e7e25167ae7023516bd3fce13@tarpon.redistogo.com:11879/
:host: tarpon.redistogo.com
:port: 11879
:password: xxxx
:inline: true
:timeout: 1

development:
  url: redis://localhost:6379/2

test:
  url: redis://localhost:6379/3
```

i try to connect to the socket from reactjs using

```
App.cable = ActionCable.createConsumer("wss://adham-chatty.heroku.com");
```

but i have this error on chrome console and the socket don't work :\

```
WebSocket connection to 'wss://adham-chatty.heroku.com/' failed: WebSocket opening handshake was canceled
```

and here is my Heroku log

```
016-01-19T17:17:22.405051+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
    2016-01-19T17:17:25.031404+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
    2016-01-19T17:17:26.521202+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
    2016-01-19T17:17:27.266810+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Puma starting in cluster mode...
    2016-01-19T17:17:27.266821+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Version 2.15.3 (ruby 2.2.2-p95), codename: Autumn Arbor Airbrush
    2016-01-19T17:17:27.266822+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
    2016-01-19T17:17:27.266822+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Environment: production
    2016-01-19T17:17:27.266823+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Process workers: 2
    2016-01-19T17:17:27.266823+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Preloading application
    2016-01-19T17:17:27.721211+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Gracefully shutting down workers...
    2016-01-19T17:17:28.101087+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] === puma shutdown: 2016-01-19 17:17:28 +0000 ===
    2016-01-19T17:17:28.101095+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Goodbye!
    2016-01-19T17:17:28.974002+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:18058
    2016-01-19T17:17:28.974157+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] Use Ctrl-C to stop
    2016-01-19T17:17:28.978252+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 0 (pid: 6) booted, phase: 0
    2016-01-19T17:17:28.994863+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
    2016-01-19T17:17:28.979382+00:00 app[web.1]: [3] - Worker 1 (pid: 10) booted, phase: 0
    2016-01-19T17:17:29.346266+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
```

what should i do?

Comment: You should have this f9e8821e7e25167ae7023516bd3fce13 in your password field, in cable.yml

Answer (score 0):

you need to set 
`config.action_cable.url` &
`config.action_cable.allowed_request_origins` &
`mount ActionCable.server` in your route